# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'igdb.wrapper'; 'igdb' is not a package" igdb-api-v4

Tags: python, api, modulenotfounderror

I am having an issue using modules installed with the api wrapper igdb-api-v4. When running this code: (client_id and token are placeholders for this conversation)

```
from igdb.wrapper import IGDBWrapper
import json

wrapper = IGDBWrapper("client_id", "token")

'''With a wrapper instance already created'''
# JSON API request
byte_array = wrapper.api_request(
            'games',
            'fields name; offset 0; where name="Hamtaro"*;',
            
          )
# parse into JSON however you like...
message = json.loads(byte_array)
print(message)
```

I receive this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'igdb.wrapper'; 'igdb' is not a package" When accessing the modules accessible by python using help('modules') python lists igdb as an available import. Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone know how to solve this issue? It was working perfectly yesterday.

Comment: Do you have a file named `igdb.py`?

Comment: yes. Do you think this is confusing the interpreter?

Comment: Dude, you are a lifesaver. Thank you for pointing this out. Amature mistake on my part.